# python print multiple value of key in different lines

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with each key containing multiple values (list):

```
one = [1,2,3]
two = [1,2,3]
three= [1,2,3]
```

It was obtained with the following line of code:

```
output_file.write('{0}\t{1}\n'.format(key,"\t".join(value)))
```

So my final printed output looks like this:

```
one 1 2 3
two 1 2 3
three 1 2 3
```

My goal now is to have the output looking like this instead:

```
one 1
one 2
one 3
two 1
two 2
…
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the key itself as delimiter

```
#key = "one"
#value = ['1','2','3']
print(key+'\t'+'\n{0}\t'.format(key).join(value))
```

**output**

```
one    1
one    2
one    3
```

Comment: this is perfect! Exactly what I wanted without knowing how to do it :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with nested for-loops:

```
for key, value_list in my_dict.iteritems():
    for value in value_list:
        output_file.write("{}\t{}\n".format(key, value))
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try it but I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack" and I am not sure what to do!

Answer (score 0):

this may also work...

```
#key = "one"
#value = ['1','2','3']
print '\n'.join(map(lambda i: key+'\t'+str(i), value))
```